# Infer nested generic types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Suppose I have

```js
interface Animal {}

interface Group<A extends Animal> {}
```

And I want to make an interface generic over Group

```js
interface AnimalGroupProps<G extends Group<A>, A extends Animal> {
  withGroup: () => G
  // We want to be able to reference A in the interface, for use like this:
  withLeader: () => A
}
```

I want animal group props to be generic over the group type. But the A
extends Animal seems redundant. I'd like to be able to say:

```js
interface AnimalGroupProps<G extends Group<A>>
```

And have TypeScript figure it out. But TypeScript wants A to be declared, so I
have to use the previous snippet's pattern.

```js
class Wolf implements Animal {}

class WolfPack implements Group<Wolf> {}

function AnimalPlanetWolves ({withGroup, withLeader}: AnimalGroupProps<WolfPack, Wolf>) {}
//                          This is the really annoying part --------------------^^^^
```

All users of AnimalGroupProps have to specify both generic parameters, even
though one of them is entirely redundant. In my actual codebase, that would be a
lot of redundancy.

---

In the above example WolfPack was not a generic type. What if there was a
generic type that you wanted to pass to AnimalGroupProps? It's actually even
worse:

```js
interface Flock<A extends Animal> extends Group<A> {}

class Geese implements Animal {}

function AnimalPlanetBirds ({withGroup, withLeader}: AnimalGroupProps<Flock<Geese>, Geese>) {}
```

Comment: Does `Group<A>` have any members that involve `A`? It should.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Indeed is does in the real use case. For the Group example, you could have an addMember: (A) => void

Comment: So you could use `interface AnimalGroupProps<G extends Group<Animal>> { withLeader: () => Parameters<G['addMember']>[0] }` but ccarton's answer provides a better approach in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Typescript has a syntax to infer nested types.

```
type AnimalForGroup<G> = G extends Group<infer A> ? A : never
```

You still need to list `A` in the template arguments but you can give it a default value:

```
interface AnimalGroupProps<G extends Group<A>, A extends Animal = AnimalForGroup<G>>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had come across infer, but incorrectly thought it wasn't applicable.